# Python Game using pyGame with Window Menu elements

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, pygame

Here's the deal. I'm trying to write an arkanoid clone game and the thing is that I need a window menu like you get in pyGTK. For example File->(Open/Save/Exit) .. something like that and opening an "about" context where the author should be written.

I'm already using pyGame for writting the game logic. I've tried pgu to write the GUI but that doesn't help me, altough it has those menu elements I'm taking about, you can't include the screen of the game in it's container.

Does anybody know how to include such window menus with the usage of pyGame ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wxPython allows you to integrate a Pygame window inside of a "normal" wxPython window - check out their [wiki entry](http://wiki.wxpython.org/IntegratingPyGame) for how to do it. This should allow you to have a normal window (with File/Help/etc.) menus, but have a Pygame surface to which you can draw for your game.

Comment: Watch out, PyGame isn't designed for this type of use there are a lot of issues with keyboard input getting grabbed away by PyGame, so as long as you only need a Menu you'll be fine, but if you need a GUI that takes more than mouse clicks you will run into major problems.

Comment: I just needed the about screen to popup from menu in order to display some info and the author