# How to create this tkinter menubar for pygame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, menubar

I want to create a menubar in pygame exactly like this one in tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)

editmenu.add_separator()

editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=donothing)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the tkinter code but does anyone know how to create something in pygame that does this the exact same way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I used the os.environ to combine pyGame with tkiter, so there is a pygame window within your tkinter one:

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *
import os
```

I added a frame for the pygame to be in:

```
def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)

editmenu.add_separator()

editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=donothing)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)

embed = Frame(root, width=640, height=480)
embed.pack()
```

And here is the added environ:

```
# Tell pygame's SDL window which window ID to use
os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
# Show the window so it's assigned an ID.
root.update()

# Usual pygame initialization
pygame.init()

# Dimensions should match those used in the embed frame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

running = True
def done():
    global running
    running = False

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", done)
while running:
    # game logic goes here
    pygame.display.flip()  # (or pygame.display.update())
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Hope it helps somehow!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is **not** possible to integrate a *tkinter* menubar in *pygame*, they are different tools.

The only thing I see you can do is to create directly the menubar with *pygame* , using just one part of the screen for the main scene and the other for the menubar, which could be created with buttons (created with rectangles or similar objects).

You have also another option, that is to create a separate *tkinter* root window (not advisable, because you would have 2 main loops fighting one another: the one from the *tkinter* application and the one from the *pygame* application), and run it in parallel with the *pygame* main application.

These are some posts that could help you for the second option:

1. [Is there anything I need aware of using Tkinter and pygame together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291274/is-there-anything-i-need-aware-of-using-tkinter-and-pygame-together)
2. [What gui toolkit should I use with Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343221/what-gui-toolkit-should-i-use-with-pygame?lq=1)
3. [What's the best way to add a GUI to a Pygame application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142912/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-gui-to-a-pygame-application?lq=1)
4. [Mac and Windows compatible GUI for Python, which is easy to install and works with pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726974/mac-and-windows-compatible-gui-for-python-which-is-easy-to-install-and-works-wi?lq=1)
5. [Python Game using pyGame with Window Menu elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618446/python-game-using-pygame-with-window-menu-elements?rq=1)

Apparently, you could also use the library [*wxPython*](http://www.wxpython.org), which allows you to integrate a *pygame* window inside of a *normal* *wxPython* window.